# Is it good practice to include a setter in my object even if I know I will never need it

Tags: java, object, setter, getter

An interesting question came up today. Is it good practice to great a setter for a field that I know I will never need to re-set after the constructor?

P.S. I, of course, understand the reasons for using a private field and a getter vs. a public field, that makes sense, but *should* I really make a setter if I am not going to use it?

P.P.S. referring specifically to Java, although it shouldn't really matter what platform.

Comment: What you're defining is a readonly field, which is a perfectly natural thing. I'd say there's no reason to build a setter, so don't do it. In fact, this is exactly how you'd build an immutable class - populate all the fields in the constructor, then they can never be changed again. If you determine in the future that you need a setter, then by all means, put it in, but don't build things that you don't think you'll need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By not creating a setter and only allowing the field to be set through the constructor, you have created an immutable field. Once you create an instance of your class, that value will never change.

Note: The statement above will not hold if the value return by your getter is itself mutable. Say, if returning an instance of `ArrayList`, someone can use that reference to add and remove items in that list. Look at `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList` to fix that. Even a `java.util.Date` can be changed if you return it in a getter. To fix that, you can use JodaTime (or other similar third-party date classes), or wait for Java 8.

In my humble (and other's not always so humble) opinion(s) imutability is a great thing that makes software less buggy and easier to maintain.

Comment: The spirit of this response is correct and spot on.  However, it is important to keep in mind that a read only field is not necessarily a guarantee of immutability.  If the field is a reference type and the getter publishes the reference to an external client -or- the client maintains a reference to the field's object after construction ... then it becomes possible to mutate the immutable object.

Comment: @scottb Absolutely! For example a field that is a List should not be exposed with a getMyList that returns the collection itself. That would, as you suggest, allow others to update the content of that collection.

Answer (score 2):

It just depends.

If your class is part of an exported API and you have reason to believe that the clients of your API will have occasion to use a setter then it may make good sense to include one.

Here's the truth about getters and setters, though.

If your class has them, then your class is mutable.  Mutable data and mutable objects are what they are.  If your design intent specifies that this API will always be single-threaded, then you have no problems.

However, even in single-threaded apps, you should aspire to create immutable objects wherever possible.  The downside to immutable objects is that there is no role for getters and setters in them (** see note).

A compromise is the Builder Pattern (Bloch, et al. Effective Java 2nd Ed.).  In this patters, you use a mutable helper object to set the fields for your object ... and then when you're ready, your helper object uses the data you've set to create an immutable instance of the object you want.

Use mutable objects when your needs are simple and there's no concerns over contention or concurrency.  But remember, the more mutable your object is, the harder it is to reason about its state.  And the harder it is to reason about its state, the potentially more difficult it is to enforce invariants and maintain security.  An object that can have only one state solves almost all of these problems.  Especially if your class is a value class, you should try to create immutable objects when you can.

(**) note: it is, of course, possible to have setters for an immutable class.  In such a case, the setter instantiates a new, immutable object, thus preserving its immutability.  The String class relies upon this strategy.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good practice to create a setter for a field that I know I will **never need to re-set after the constructor**?

If you *know* this in advance, then, by all means, write it in your code. Make that field `final`, and then you won't have any doubts, as the compiler itself won't let you define a setter.

This avoids writing a method *"because it may be expected"*, and is also a step forward in keeping the code clean and verifiable, in my opinion. You're declaring things just as they are, which also eliminates the need to test the immutability of the value.